# If $f(x , t)$ is continuous when $ x \in [a , b]$ , then $F'(t) = f( t , t)$ for $t \in [a , b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

The fundamental theorem of calculus: If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a , b]$  , then $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x) dx$  is differentiable on $[a , b]$ and $F'(t) = f(t)$ for $t \in [a , b]$.

My question is if the integrand involves $t$ also , will our assertion remain unchanged?

If $f(x , t)$ is continuous when $ x \in [a , b]$  , then $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x , t) dx$  is differentiable on $[a , b]$ and $F'(t) = f( t , t)$ for $t \in [a , b]$.-----Is this statement true?

If $F(x) = \int_1^x (\ln{\frac{x}{z}})e^z dz$ then $F'(x) = (\ln{\frac{x}{x}})e^x - (\ln{\frac{x}{1}})e^1$.------Is this statement true?

**EDIT**   I am trying to prove this statement--- If $f(x , t)$ is continuous when $ x \in [a , b]$  , then $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x , t) dx$  is differentiable on $[a , b]$ and $F'(t) = f( t , t)$ for $t \in [a , b]$. Can anyone please check if I have gone wrong somewhere?

Let's say $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x , t) dx$

We will check differentiability at the point $t = c \in ( a , b)$ . As $f(x , t)$ is continuous on $x \in [a , b]$ ,  we will get a $\delta$ such that  for $x \in N'(c ,\delta)$ ,   $f(c , c)  - \epsilon <  f(x , c) < f(c , c)  + \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow \int_c^{c+h} f(c , c)  - \epsilon  < \int_c^{c+h}  f(x , c)  < \int_c^{c+h} f(c , c)  + \epsilon $ where  $c+h \in N'(c ,\delta)$.

$\Rightarrow - \epsilon  < [\frac{F(c+h) - F(c)}{h} - f(c , c)] < + \epsilon $
 where  $c+h \in N'(c ,\delta)$.

So we can say $F'(c) = f(c , c)$

Can anyone please tell me  where I have gone wrong?

Comment: No, this is not true in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Can you please tell me where I have gone wrong in the proof?@Chappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x,t)=t$ for  a counter-example.

Your proof only shows that the derivative of $\int_a^{t} f(x,c)d$ is $f(c,c)$ (which is of course true). When you differentiate $F$ you cannot keep $t$ in $f(x,t)$ fixed at $t=c$. You will have to vary it. $F'(c)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\int_a^{c+h} f(x,c+h) dx-\int_a^{c} f(x,c) dx } h$.

Comment: Can you please check my question again? I have written a proof of my statement can you please check it and tell me where I have gone wrong?@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: I  understood from your counter example that I am going wrong.. But I can not find where I am making mistake. It will be great if you kindly point out my mistake..@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @sani I have edited my answer.

Comment: I think in the last line it will be $F'(c)$.@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @sani Yes, that was   a typo.

Comment: I am really grateful to you sir. I understood where  I am misunderstanding. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Actually original problem was [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618399/fx-int-e-ex-ln-fracx-ln-t-dt-then-what-is-f3/3618417#3618417]