# $f(x) = \int_e ^ {e^x} \ln{\frac{x}{\ln t}} dt$. Then what is $f'(3) $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f(x) = \int_e ^ {e^x} \ln{\frac{x}{\ln t}} dt$. Then what is $f'(3) $?

I know I can solve it by using the following theorem.

[image]

I need to first verify that all the functions here satisfy their conditions. Then I will be able to say that I can solve this problem by using this rule.

But this question has been given in a 10+2 exam. How can I make my students understand this solution? Can anyone please tell me? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

**EDIT** Some of  the answerers below are suggesting to do the following::

$f(x) = \int_e ^ {e^x} [\ln x - \ln{(\ln t)} ]dt$.

I do not think it can be done. Since the domain of $x$ can include the negative real numbers also. If $x <0$ , then in the interval$(e^x , e)$ , $\ln x$ and  $\ln{(\ln t)}$ will not remain defined.

What will we do if we were to find $f'(-3)$?

Comment: Multivariable chain rule would be the way to explain this - seeking out every dependence and simply adding the derivative w.r.t. each dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify using rules of $\log$ first. $$f(x)=\int_e^{e^x}\ln(x)-\ln(\ln(t))dt=\ln(x)\int_e^{e^x}dt-\int_e^{e^x}\ln(\ln(t))dt$$

Now you don't need to differentiate under the integral sign. Just use FTC.

Comment: I have added an edit..Can you please check?@user658409

Comment: Can you please read the edit once? @user658409

Comment: Can you please read the edit once? @user658409

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)= \int_{e}^{e^x} \ln x~ dt-\int_{e}^{e^x} \ln(\ln(t)) dt
\implies f(x)= \ln x (e^x-e) -\int_{e}^{e^x} \ln(\ln t) dt$$
Now D.w.t. $x$ appllying Lebnitz Rule, we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}(e^x-e)+e^{x}\ln x -e^x\ln x$$
$$\implies f'(3)=\frac{e^3-e}{3}$$
**Doing it OP's way using the genral Lebnitz Rule as stated in his answer**
$$f'(x)= e^x \ln \frac{x}{x}+0+\int_e^{e^x}  \frac{\ln t}{x}\frac{1}{\ln t} dt=
\frac{1}{x}(e^x-e) \implies f'(3)=\frac{1}{3}(e^3-e)$$

Comment: I have added an edit..Can you please check?@Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Comment: Thanks I have edited it now.

Comment: Can you please read the  edit once?@Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Comment: It would be great if you would say if I am wrong in the edit?

Comment: @sani you may see my edit  for doing it your way.

Comment: I do not want to use Libnitz Rule. Can you please read my question once again? @Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Comment: You may not have understood what I am saying..@Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Answer (score 0):

You could also use  that $\displaystyle\ln{x\over \ln t} =\ln x -\ln \ln t$. In this way you can separate them and using the lineality of the integral you would have an elemental function plus another that is eassier to derivate since there is no $x$ in the integral.

Comment: I have added an edit..Can you please check?@Richard Medina Rodriguez

Comment: Note that $x$ can not be negative. Since $t\in(e,e^x)$ then $\ln t>0$. Then for the first logarithm in the integral to be well defined $x>0$. So there is no problem. And the domain of $f$ is $x>0$.

Comment: No.    $x$ can be negative..Can you not find $\int _2^1 f(x) $ ? upper limit of the integration may not be greater than lower limit.

Comment: If we assume $x<0$ then we would have $$\int_{e^x}^1 h(x,t)dt+\int_{1}^e h(x,t)dt$$ where $h(x,t)$ is the argument of your integral. There the first integral is well define since $\ln t<0$ in $(e^x,1)$ and $x<0$. But in the second integral the function $f$ we have is not well define since $x<0$ but in the interval $(1,e),\ \ln t>0$. So we can not have $x<0$.